# Remove Space From Header and UL Tag

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to not have a space between the text and the list?  I have tried with the `<p>` tag and w/o and it makes no difference, I am beginning to think that the tag `<ul>` automatically adds it in...

```
<p>Please Get These Items At The Store:<p>
<ul>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Grapes</li>
  <li>Walnuts</li>
  <li>Pecans</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
</ul>
```

Desired output is I would like "Please Get These Items At The Store" to sit directly on top of Apples, not have the added whitespace between them.

Comment: p and ul have a default padding and margin. you can overcome this issue just by this line of css p,ul{ margin:0; padding:0;}

Comment: Please refrain from asking such basic question online. it's almost as asking how to turn on/off your computer.. There is a threshold for what to ask.

Comment: @vsync - Apalogies, I did not know it was a "basic" ? as I was struggling with discovering how to achieve it.  Moving forward I will do as requested.

Comment: well, you only need fundamental CSS to answer your question,  and you seem not to know any CSS, and that is far below the minimum threshold. please at least learn the most basic things, it only takes 1-2 hours on youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default margin from the `<p>` and `<ul>`

```css
p, ul {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<p>Please Get These Items At The Store:
  <p>
    <ul>
      <li>Apples</li>
      <li>Grapes</li>
      <li>Walnuts</li>
      <li>Pecans</li>
      <li>Bread</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the `<p>` and `ul` tags have a margin which are causing this behavior.  You can set the margins to zero to get rid of the behavior.  Following CSS would set the margins to zero for `<p>` and `<ul>` tags.

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span>Please Get These Items At The Store:</span>
<ul>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Grapes</li>
  <li>Walnuts</li>
  <li>Pecans</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @RashidAbib Do you want the bullets for the list?

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada - yes bullets are a requirement